# Proper way of using UNION with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a question, what is the proper query/way of segregating data from SQL? I want to separate time in and time out based on "AM/PM" date time. I got an error there and I don't know why. This is my query below.

```
SELECT empno, time_in, time_out FROM ( 
                SELECT empno, datetime AS time_in FROM august2023 WHERE empno LIKE '%5787%' AND datetime LIKE '%AM%' GROUP BY datetime, empno ORDER BY datetime
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT empno, datetime AS time_out FROM august2023 WHERE empno LIKE '%5787%' AND datetime LIKE '%PM%' GROUP BY datetime, empno ORDER BY datetime
                ) UNIONS
                GROUP BY empno
```

Here is the table.

```
| datetime| empno|
|:--------|:---------|
| 08/01/2023 02:32:24 AM| 5-787  |
| 08/01/2023 04:06:36 PM | 5-787 |
```

I want to transform that into this,

```
| empno| time in | time out |
|:--------|:---------|:------|
| 5-787  | 08/01/2023 02:32:24 AM| 08/01/2023 04:06:36 PM |
```

I will deeply appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!